# why query is not runned by codeigniter db?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem running the query in codeigniter.

here is the code:

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function user_login($username, $password) {
        $sql = "select username,password from login_users where username='$username' && password='$password'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

I don't know what seems to be wrong but query doesn't run and return error.I am using codeigniter 3.Please guide me

Comment: `&&` is php and `AND` is mysql !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'AND' instead of '&&'

```
select username,password from login_users where username='$username' AND password='$password'
```

Comment: i have used that too but the same problem.

Comment: actually the code runs in previous version of codeigniter bt not in new version

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function user_login($username, $password) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username,password FROM login_users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use password and username variables like so `$username = $this->input->post('username');` and  `$password = $this->input->post('password');`

```
function user_login() {
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');

$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);

$query = $this->db->get('login_users');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    // Or return $query->result_array();
    return $query->row_array();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Also I would recommend using php **password_hash();** for creating passwords and **password_verfiy()** to check passwords

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

**Login With Callback Example Only**

```
public function index() {

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_checkuser');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('login_view');
} else {
   redirect('user_cp');
}

}

public function checkuser() {
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('model_user');

if ($this->model_user->user_login() == FALSE) {

$this->form_validation->set_message('checkuser', 'User Login Information Incorrect');

return FALSE;

} else {

return TRUE;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Active Record query

```
$this->db->select('username,password');
$this->db->from('login_users');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $row = $query->result_array();
    return $row;
}
```